# What's the correct IAM Policy to allow users add Ingress/Egress rules in a VPC security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, rules, policy, amazon-iam

I have tried this, but it fails on the IAM Policy Simulator.
Got this policy from AWS docs.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Action": [
       "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
       "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
       "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
       "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress"],
     "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:Account-Number:security-group/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:Vpc": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:Account-Number:vpc/vpc-id"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully tested the referenced [IAM policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html) via the [IAM Policy Simulator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UsingPolicySimulatorGuide/iam-policy-simulator-guide.html) - the policy simulator can be quite picky/tricky though and it took me a few attempts to get it right as well, here's what to look out for:

1. Obviously you need to replace *Account-Number* and *vpc-id* in the policy with the actual values from your AWS account - presumably you did this already.
2. Since you have created a policy for a specific *Resource* `arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:Account-Number:security-group/*`, you need to ensure to also enter the identical [Amazon Resource Name (ARN)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) as the value for `Resource` in the *Simulation Settings*.
3. Similarly, since you have created a policy with a specific [Condition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition), the simulator asks to enter a value for the `ec2:Vpc` condition key in the *Simulation Settings* - you need to ensure to enter a full ARN as the value here rather than just the VPC id itself, i.e. something like `arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:Account-Number:vpc/vpc-12345678` rather than just `vpc-12345678`!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. 
I guess I was doing something wrong on the simulator because i ran a command on the CLI and it did work as expected for this policy.
I tried to update this question but since I'm new to this forum i have to wait 8 hours to respond my own questions.